# angular2 template, how to pass arguments other than variables

Tags: angular, templates

In angular2, given this code

```
<div id="{{window.id}}_body" class="session_body hidden">
    <div class="tab" *ngFor="let bookmark of window.bookmarks; let i = index;" id="{{window.id}}_{{i}}_bookmark">
        <bookmark [id]="window.id"+'_'+"i"+'_bookmark' [bookmark]="bookmark.url"></bookmark>
    </div>
</div>
```

It fails because when I try to pass the variable [id]

```
<bookmark [id]="window.id"+'_'+"i"+'_bookmark' [bookmark]="bookmark.url">
```

I am not passing a simple variable, but a string that uses variables.

Can it be done? Or I should pass the variables "window.id" and "i" separately and then re-construct the id from this later on (which is what I'd like to avoid), like

```
<bookmark [id]="window.id" [index]="i" [bookmark]="bookmark.url">
```

Comment: Yes! definitively, if you add this as an answer I'll close it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works.

You just got entangled in your simple/double quotes :

```
<bookmark [id]="window.id+'_'+i+'_bookmark'">
```